# URL Redirection in magento

Tags: url, url-rewriting, redirect

i had a website example.com in woo-commerce. So there was an URL created **example.com/shop**.

Now i have moved to Magento 1.9.3.2 now that URL doesnot exist.
So i have used URL rewrite from magento admin which redirect **example.com/shop** to **example.com/** but its **not working**. But its working like that **example.com/index.php/shop** to **example.com/**

My question is how can i redirect **example.com/shop** to **example.com/**  not **example.com/index.php/shop** to **example.com/**.

please help me out this i have tried too many htaccess code also for this but they are not working..

Comment: Show us your htaccess code.

Comment: for rewriting currently using this code previous codes are removed

RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/.*$ http://jaganhardware.com